# Spring 5 WebClient NIO Features and Issue Domain, working with Spring Webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I am using latest version of Spring - Spring 5.

I am developing WebService "Aggregator" of http clients, that sort of like routes requests to external WebServices, receives the response back receives the response back, does some data manipulation and replies back to the client of my HTTP Service.

For creating http clients within my App, I am basically using the new WebClient available for building Reactive App.

My code goes around the following style:

```
private WebClient client = WebClient
            .builder()
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector())
            .baseUrl("http://webservice")
            .build();

// Later calling like:



client.method(HttpMethod.POST) // Or GET, whatever
      .uri(builder -> builder
             .path("search")                                  
             .build())
      .headers(defaultHeaders())
      .exchange()
      .block()
```

Later on, I expose the results of this call in my own HTTP API, which I will not post here for simplicity.

As part of this APP, I use Netty, as en embedded HTTP layer for serving clients of my App. (It also came as a default one, when I selected the **Spring Webflux** in Spring Boot Starter).

My use case is not necessarily a Reactive Application, I don't need to perform any Streaming, or back-pressure logic.

However, my understanding is that using Netty, I can do all requests to external HTTP Services in a Non Blocking Fashion, which would be useful for my use case.

**Questions are:**

1 . Is that correct with regards to the NIO Features, I am potentially benefiting from?

2 . If am using this WebClient interface of Spring 5, am loosing something, or gaining something in my use case, since I am not doing reactive stuff?

3 . Should the `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient` fulfil my requirements?

4 . Is the WebClient a good option for building Functional Pipelines? I ask because I intend, to take the result of one call, and make a subsequent call, and I am planning to use **CompletableFutures**, which I saw available in the WebClient API?